# Cannot Load Such File - Active Support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, activesupport

I am trying to start a rails server, but I get the error:

```
/Users/<username>/RubyWorkspace/<appname>/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support (LoadError)
```

When I go to /vendor/bundle and list the gems, I don't see active support:

```
actioncable-5.0.0       minitest-5.9.0
actionmailer-5.0.0      multi_json-1.12.1
actionpack-5.0.0        nio4r-1.2.1
actionview-5.0.0        pkg-config-1.1.7
activejob-5.0.0         rack-2.0.1
activemodel-5.0.0       rack-test-0.6.3
activerecord-5.0.0      rails-5.0.0
arel-7.0.0              rails-dom-testing-2.0.1
builder-3.2.2           rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3
byebug-9.0.0            railties-5.0.0
byebug-9.0.5            rake-11.2.2
coffee-rails-4.2.1      rb-fsevent-0.9.7
coffee-script-2.4.1     rb-inotify-0.9.7
coffee-script-source-1.10.0 sass-3.4.22
concurrent-ruby-1.0.2       sass-rails-5.0.5
debug_inspector-0.0.2       spring-1.7.1
erubis-2.7.0            spring-1.7.2
execjs-2.7.0            spring-watcher-listen-2.0.0
ffi-1.9.14              sprockets-3.6.3
globalid-0.3.6          sprockets-rails-3.1.1
i18n-0.7.0              thor-0.19.1
jbuilder-2.4.1          thread_safe-0.3.5
jbuilder-2.5.0          tilt-2.0.5
jquery-rails-4.1.1      turbolinks-5.0.0
listen-3.0.8            turbolinks-source-5.0.0
loofah-2.0.3            tzinfo-1.2.2
mail-2.6.4              uglifier-3.0.0
method_source-0.8.2     web-console-3.1.1
mime-types-3.1          web-console-3.3.1
mime-types-data-3.2016.0521 websocket-driver-0.6.4
mini_portile2-2.1.0     websocket-extensions-0.1.2
```

But when I run bundle update, bundler says that it is using active support:

```
Using rake 11.2.2
....
Using activesupport 5.0.0
....
Bundle updated!
Gems in the group production were not installed.
```

One thing that I believe could be causing the error, but I'm not sure, is when I run gem env, under gem paths, it shows:

```
- GEM PATHS:
 - /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
 - /Users/<username>/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
```

Do I need to fix the gem paths, do I need to reinstall active support in a different directory, or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Are you running server with bundler, i.e. `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: I wasn't, but I tried it and the same error showed up

Comment: If it is rails project there must be Gemfile and you should run `bundle install` to install all gems. Did you do it?

Comment: Yes I have done that recently

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Same error different stack. I was working with [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com/) and ran into this issue. Where:

1. `gem list` was showing that `activesupport` was installed (e.g. `Using activesupport 5.0.2`).
2. My `bundle exec rackup` was still failing with `LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_support/all`
3. Using Ruby 2.3.0 installed through [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)

**Fix**: Trouble shooting lead me to realize I'd run `sudo bundle install` instead of `bundle install`. As such, `activesupport` was installed for the `root` user not my user. I then ran:

1. Uninstalled the gem with `gem uninstall activesupport` (`y`es to the prompts)
2. Reinstalled it on the proper user `bundle install`
3. Ran `bundle exec rackup` to successfully start my app

**TLDR**: File permissions issue. Gem was installed on `root` and attempting to be accessed as `non-root`. Did `gem uninstall all` > `y`es ~50k times > `bundle install` > app boots without problems.